# Type not inferred by GADT match and functional depenency

Tags: haskell

I have a misunderstanding of the Haskell type system that I think may be common, but I cannot find an explanation for the specific type-checking failure shown by this simple example:

```
{-#LANGUAGE GADTs, FunctionalDependencies #-}

module GaF where

class XDeterminesY x y | x -> y
instance XDeterminesY Int Double

data Wrapper x where
    WrappedInt :: Wrapper Int

func :: XDeterminesY x y => Wrapper x -> y -> Double
func WrappedInt a = a
```

GHC complains that it cannot deduce `y ~ Double` from the context `x ~ Int`. I imagined that to perform such a deduction was the whole point of declaring the functional dependency.

Comment: Interesting. The equivalent with `type family Y x`;  `type instance Y Int = Double` does typecheck.

Comment: I believe GADTs are not the issue here: `fun :: XDeterminesY Int y => y -> Double ; fun a = a` already raises a type error.

Comment: Instance resolution doesn't happen at declaration. Only at call site.

Comment: Yep, this just isn't one of the features that fundeps provide. Pretty annoying. I don't think you're misunderstanding anything.

Comment: Hmm. By my intuition of the type system it would be weird if this worked. The type signature says the caller can pick *any* `x` and `y` provided it also give you a matching `XDeterminesY` instance. Then inside a branch of a pattern match you want to determine that the caller *must* have chosen `Double`, based on re-solving the `XDeterminesY x y` constraint (rather than relying on the opaque passed-in instance) now that you know that `x` was `Int`, since the fundep allows it to be solved with this partial information? That's much more indirect reasoning than I expect from the typechecker.

Comment: @leftaroundabout How do you write the signature for `func` using that type family instead of the class? Is it `func :: Wrapper x -> Y x -> Double`? If that's what works it fits with my intuition, since there's no separate `y` variable chosen by the caller where we need to infer that they must have "chosen" a specific type.

Comment: @Ben "That's much more indirect reasoning than I expect from the typechecker." Indeed. What if there were other instances for `XDeterminesY` and/or other equations for `func`?

Comment: @AntC Theoretically (if you trust the fundep), once you know that `x ~ Int` and you can see the `XDeterminesY Int Double` instance, there shouldn't be another instance so you can decide that was the one the caller *must* have given you; even if there are any other instances you can't there should have been an error somewhere preventing them from making this call with any other instance. I just don't expect the type checker to follow all of that reasoning (mainly the "re-solving the constraint in order to infer what the passed in instance must be" part) to *allow* this call.

Comment: I'd like to gain that intuition too. So what is the difference between the type checking that is done at the declaration compared with that at the call site? Is there a good rule of thumb for where a fundef has effect and where it doesn't?

Comment: @PaulGardiner My understanding is that fundeps are purely an aid to instance resolution; where an instance has to be chosen, there are some situations that would fail with an ambiguous type error that a fundep will allow to proceed. Given an instance is able to be selected it behaves identically whether or not there was a fundep. And my intuition is that any function with a constraint is *not* going to be doing instance selection (for that constraint); it uses the instance passed in by the caller. So I don't expect fundeps to have any effect on the constrained function, only the caller.

Comment: @PaulGardiner I should say that I don't know that all of that is absolutely correct by the spec (hence the weasel words like "My understanding is" and "my intuition is"). It's just the mental model I have built up through having read the user's guide in the past, and through usage. So I'm pretty confident my conception mostly makes correct predictions, but may not have much to do with how things are implemented, and might be wrong in corner cases I haven't thought of.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I imagined that to perform such a deduction was the whole point of declaring the functional dependency.

Unfortunately, this is not the case. FunDeps never refine rigid type variables as it happens during pattern matching on a GADT. Intuitively, they *should* do that in some cases, but they do not. I guess this is because they appeared in Haskell long before GADTs were a thing, so there was no precedent.

It is pretty annoying, I concur. That's why I believe that type families are in general a much better idea. FunDeps, in my opinion, should be replaced by type families when it is possible to do so (note that in `class C a b c | a->c, b->c` we indeed can not).

Note in passing that a similar failure can be observed in the *injective* type families extension: one would expect GHC to infer `a ~ b` from `F a ~ F b`, but it does not.

Anyway, I think you are now wondering "if this was not the point of FunDeps, what is their point?". Well, consider:

```
class C a b | a -> b where
   foo :: a -> b -> String
   bar :: a -> String

instance C Bool Int where ...
```

Without FunDeps, a call like `bar True` would be ambiguous: `C Bool Int` in one instance we could use to resolve the constraint, but there could be another one. Here, the issue is that the type `bar :: a -> String` does not involve `b`, so there is no way to know if we can safely commit to the instance. The type is deemed to be ambiguous.

With FunDeps, instead, we promise there will be no other instance, so a type involving only `a` is no longer ambiguous, and instance resolution can work just fine with that.

(By the way, nowadays such ambiguities can be manually resolved at the call site with type applications, but this was not the case in the past.)